# How to design a database where I can add unsettled number of items

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a form in which I fill following things:

```
Nick: SbsNick;
Item: SomeItem1; Price: PriceOfItem1
Item: SomeItem2; Price: PriceOfItem2  
Item: SomeItem3; Price: PriceOfItem3
................................
```

And I can add items with varying number of inputs. It means that each **Nick** can have different number of items.

I want to create the database where I can query

```
SELECT ? FROM items WHERE Item="SomeItem"
```

and receive all nicks and prices of SomeItem, i.e. I want to end up with the table like that:

```
Nick   |Price
-------------
Jack   |20
BlackB |18
Karl   |25
.............
```

I have a problem with designing such database, cause I feel that I lack of one additional dimension. If I want to fix ammount of tables I see that I need unlimited amount of columns in some table. If I want to bound ammount of tables and columns I see that cells must behave like array.

Is there a clever way to design such database?

Comment: Step 1 - determine the business requirements you have to satisfy.  Step 2 - design a database that will satisfy those requirements.  Step 3 - write the user interfaces that talk to your database.  In other words, you are doing things in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to study about Relational Data Bases.
I can not understand what is your exact problem.

You need three tables:
`USERS, ITEMS, PURCHASES`. One for representing the users, another for the items and the last for representing the **relation** between both of them.

```
 USERS(ID_USER, NAME, NICK, REGISTER_DATE)

 ITEMS(ID_ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE)

 PURCHASES(ID_PURCHASE, ID_USER, ID_ITEM, PRICE, PURCHASE_DATE)
```

I have used the name PURCHASES because I personally don't know the exact nature of the relation between users and items in your problem, be free to name that third table whatever you want.

There is no need for extra new columns for each purchase that the user does in table USERS nor in table ITEMS, you only have to insert a new row in table PURCHASES.

Comment: Amount of items that users can add in my case is very large and user can do "purchase" just once. So in your solution I would end up in "purchases" with id_user repetiting in sort of clumps. I see it works but I wonder if it can be done without so huge table "purchases"

Comment: @FallenApart, this is the common way of doing it (though i still don't get your requirements/business logic). We call it relational database, because we define relations between items/objects/entities like RubioRic suggested.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Problem with my view was that I thought naively that I can avoid creating such table "purchuses". But your solution will work for me and I use it.